# Protobuf message from CPP to python

Tags: c++, python-3.x, protobuf-c, protobuf-python

I have define my protobuf message that is serialize in CPP and send to Python program thank to a wrapper. On CPP side, the protobuf message is generate as std::string

Here is how I generate in cpp my message:

```
  ....
  std::string data = results.SerializeAsString();
  return data;
```

In Python, I just connect my CPP wrapper and I try to get the string message. With a common message, the communication between CPP and Python works properly but with the protobuf serialized message, I get that error:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 13: invalid start byte
```

Is there a way to encore in CPP the string message to be readable in Python?

Comment: Protobuf uses `UTF-8` encoding to pass strings. So if your string contains `0xff` and it is not BOM in front of it it is invalid UTF-8 encoding. So sender side had to use string which is not UTF-8 encoded. You should show code which writes some string value into class generated protobuf.

Comment: Just to clarify `std::string data = results.SerializeAsString();` is not related to your problem.

Comment: You need to show the python code. More specifically, why are you trying to decode binary data as utf8?